# Why are my static files not served when deployed to Heroku server? (Django)

Tags: python, django, heroku

So this is a common mistake for Django users, which is static files not served in production when `Debug=False`. I've tried many methods to overcome this issue, but still cannot figure out right solution. Below is my settings.py

```
...
DEBUG = False

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'member/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'register/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

I don't see how I've done wrong.

*One thing that might be a potential cause is that I've set `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` since the initial deploy to heroku server.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.7.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> Skipping Django collectstatic since the env var DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC is set.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 102.1M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v153
```

Comment: Did you `collect static` ?

Comment: @Jonas Do I have to `collect static` every time I make changes to my static files? I did it once, and have not added any static files since then. (Made a few changes to existing ones though.)

Comment: Yep, if you add/remove/change the static files you have to re-collect them

Comment: @Jonas I see. So I have to `python manage.py collectstatic` and then deploy to heroku server, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add to your setting.py installed apps `'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic'`.
2. Add to your setting.py MIDDLEWARE `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'`
3. Add to your seeting.py these 3 lines

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles'))
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' # new
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

for the last line here you need to install `django_heroku` (not `django_on_heroku`, be careful)

For more info check this out: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-static-files.

P.S. if after this it fails because it can't find the staticfiles folder, manually create it. You have to do it only once and that's it. An empty folder and nothing more.